# jQuery Cycle and CSS setting img as cover

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I know that when you set an image as a `background-image` you can set `background-size:cover`

Is there a method of doing this  for jQuery Cycle when the image is an actual`<img>`?

```
<div>
    <img src="image1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `backgroundSize:"cover"` in the options?

Comment: @zzlalani I do not see this option on jquery Cycle

Comment: well try adding this in `cssBefore: {`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've done the following...

```
$('.aside-img div').each(function(index) {
    var imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $(this).find('img').hide();
        $(this).css({
            'background-image':'url('+imgsrc+')'
        });
});
```

Comment: That's the option, but remember there is additional js code which you can easily omit.

Comment: @Kasyx have gone with your option

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.
Remember, you can cycle also divs (not only images). So just put divs in your container and set `backgroundSize:cover;` for them and put your images as a background.

```
<div id="cycleContainer"> 
    <div style="background: url(image1.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background: url(image2.jpg)";></div>
    <div style="background: url(image3.jpg)";></div>
</div> 

#cycleContainer div {
    backgroundSize: cover;
}
```